# Insert highlighted sentence at bookmark in MS Word?

Tags: vba, insert, ms-word, highlight

So I have a userform that I use to populate a template with text at certain bookmarks. To make it easy to see what text has been inserted, I would like it to be highlighted with yellow. Is there a convenient way to do this for every text that is inserted without typing it, selecting it and then highlighting it? As an example, this is what part of my code looks like atm:

```
With ActiveDocument
   Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
   '[highlight=yellow].Bookmarks("Modtager").Range.Text = TxtModtager.Value[/highlight]
  .Bookmarks("Modtager").Range.Text = TxtModtager.Value
  .Bookmarks("KSnr1").Range.Text = txtKSnr.Value
  .Bookmarks("KSnr2").Range.Text = txtKSnr.Value
```

The first line doesn't seem to do anything - even without the option turned on new text is still not highlighted.

The second line is something I found at another site but had to be commented as it's not working.

The last three lines insert the actual text and I guess you could choose to select the bookmark first and then Selection.TypeText Text:="Whatever value I need", followed by selecting the new phrase again (how?) and choose .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow.

There should be a better way though, any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SetBkmkText "Modtager", TxtModtager.Value
SetBkmkText "KSnr1", txtKSnr.Value
SetBkmkText "KSnr2", txtKSnr.Value


Sub SetBkmkText(bkmk as String, NewText as String)
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bkmk).Range
        .Text = NewText 
        .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but is there no way to turn on highlighting for everything that is entered, without having to specify it for every insertion? Your example still needs 4 lines for every bookmark, which amounts to quite a lot if you have many bookmarks.

Comment: If you have many bookmarks then split that part out into a callable sub-procedure. See my edit.