# Copy from Excel and paste to Word - Troubleshooting

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

So I have a working vba code that takes a bunch of cell values in excel and places them in a specific word document I created. These values are being placed where I put bookmarks in the word document.

My problem is, about 30-40% of the time I try to run the code, it freezes up and gives and error. When I debug it, it will show a random line of code that I know works to be the source of the issue. I know my code is working because it will run all the way through more than half the time with no problem. See below for my entire code and for the error messages:

```
Sub ConvertToWord()

Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document

'Reference Word Template
Set WrdDoc = GetObject("R:\Telecom\Structural\Analysis Templates\Mount Analysis\VBA\Automated Report Generation\Mount Analysis Report Template.docm")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Select, copy and paste Cover Page
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ReportType").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K14").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K15").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K15").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
End If

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SiteInfo").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K18").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K19").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K19").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
End If
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K20").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K21").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K22").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K23").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Utilization").Select
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K25").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K25").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K26").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K26").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K27").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K27").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
End If

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Client").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K33").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K34").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K35").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MaserOffice").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K39").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K40").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K41").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Footer").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K46").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K47").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FooterSecond").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K49").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Select, copy and paste page 2
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Objective").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V31").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DocTable").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report").Range("C35:K43").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IBC").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V9").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TIA").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V10").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("WS").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V11").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EC").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V12").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("RC").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V13").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TF").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V14").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MBE").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V15").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IWS").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V16").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DIT").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V17").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MWS").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V18").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ML").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V19").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MLL").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V20").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SN").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V21").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SC").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V22").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SS").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V23").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("S").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V24").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Select, copy and paste page 3
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Loading").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("C114").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report").Range("N65:T86").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste


If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("D138").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("D138").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
End If

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AnalysisApproach").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V7").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Select, copy and paste page 4
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Two").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V26").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Three").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V27").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Seven").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V28").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Eight").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V29").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Nine").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V30").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Select, copy and paste page 5
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Results").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report").Range("C129:K153").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V32").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V32").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
End If

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Recommendation").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V33").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V34").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("RecommendationOne").Select
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V35").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V35").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V36").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V36").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
End If

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("RecommendationTwo").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V38").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V39").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Select, copy and paste page 6
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MountOne").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V45").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MountTwo").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V47").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MountThree").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V47").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MountFour").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V47").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ModNote").Select
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V44").Value = "" Then
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V44").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText
End If
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("V44").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Select, copy and paste Header
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Header").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K56").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K57").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Word Report Preview").Range("K58").Copy
WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdKeepSourceFormatting

End Sub
```

Error Message:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What happens if you put a `DoEvents` after every paste?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with VBA and coding. Can you provide an example of how to use "DoEvents" after each paste?

Comment: No need to involve the clipboard when populating bookmarks: eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684157/insert-highlighted-sentence-at-bookmark-in-ms-word/20687877#20687877

Comment: Clipboard timing is always a problem. Either use an alternate method, as Tim has suggested, or search StackOverFlow for Sleep, Wait and DoEvents as methods to slow down your code.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams !! This works. Can you help me use this fuction you referenced with keeping the source format of excel?

Comment: What kind of formatting are you trying to keep?  You could extend the Sub to apply bold/italic etc based on the cell format, but it might be complicated if your cell formats are more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how it can be done:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim wdApp, fldr, FilePath, doc As Object

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    wdApp.Visible = True

    'open a file from the same folder as the workbook
    Set doc = wdApp.documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.docx")

    SetBookmarkFromCell doc, "Test1", Sheet1.Range("A1")        'no formatting
    SetBookmarkFromCell doc, "Test2", Sheet1.Range("A2"), True  'copy formatting
    SetBookmarkFromCell doc, "Test3", Sheet1.Range("A3"), True  'copy formatting

End Sub



'Replace the text in a bookmark and optionally copy formatting from the source cell
'Preserves the bookmark
Sub SetBookmarkFromCell(oDoc As Object, sBookmark As String, c As Range, _
                        Optional CopyFormatting As Boolean = False)
    Dim BMRange As Object
    If oDoc.Range.Bookmarks.Exists(sBookmark) Then
        Set BMRange = oDoc.Range.Bookmarks(sBookmark).Range
        With BMRange
            .Text = c.Value 'or .Text
            If CopyFormatting Then
                .Font.Bold = c.Font.Bold
                .Font.Italic = c.Font.Italic
                .Font.Color = c.Font.Color
                If c.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
                    .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = c.Interior.Color
                End If
                'add any other formatting properties here...
            End If
        End With
        oDoc.Range.Bookmarks.Add sBookmark, BMRange 'recreates the bookmark
    Else
      MsgBox "Bookmark '" & sBookmark & "' not found in document '" & oDoc.Name & "'" & _
              vbCrLf & "Content not updated"
    End If
End Sub
```